# Extract bullets or bulleted lists from docx

Tags: c#, xml, docx

is there a way to extract bullets 
or bulleted lists from a docx document;
I' m using Docx library with c#

Comment: Probably; what have you tried so far?

Comment: i get the text for each paragrph via paragraph.Text property.

Comment: I use regex to for search the special \u2022 character with no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok. It just needed to use the latest version of DocX dll. It has a funcion 
IsListItem